# Resize image before upload django without saving

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, python-imaging-library

I am trying to crop and resize before uploading image, here is spinnet of my code -

```
            x,y,w,h = self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h
            image = Image.open(self.cleaned_data.get('profile_image'))
            try:
                for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys() :
                    if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation]=='Orientation' : break
                exif=dict(image._getexif().items())
                if exif[orientation] == 3 :
                    image=image.rotate(180, expand=True)
                elif exif[orientation] == 6 :
                    image=image.rotate(270, expand=True)
                elif exif[orientation] == 8 :
                    image=image.rotate(90, expand=True)
            except:
                pass
            cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w+x, h+y))
            resized_image = cropped_image.resize((160, 160), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            filename = 'image'
            new_image = InMemoryUploadedFile(resized_image,'ImageField',\
                            "%s.jpg" % filename , 'image/jpeg', resized_image.__sizeof__(), None)
            self.cleaned_data['profile_image'] = resized_image
            return super(UpdateUserProfileForm, self).save()
```

this is not working, resized image is not saved instead original get saved. I have to save it in  `InMemoryUploadedFile` because I am using AWS S3 bucket for media files and it doesn't support absolute path for saving images.

Previously in development I am using this code -

```
            x,y,w,h = self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h
            try:
                image = Image.open(update_form.profile_image)
                for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys() :
                    if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation]=='Orientation' : break
                exif=dict(image._getexif().items())
                if exif[orientation] == 3 :
                    image=image.rotate(180, expand=True)
                elif exif[orientation] == 6 :
                    image=image.rotate(270, expand=True)
                elif exif[orientation] == 8 :
                    image=image.rotate(90, expand=True)
            except:
                pass
            cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w+x, h+y))
            resized_image = cropped_image.resize((160, 160), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            resized_image.save(update_form.profile_image.path)
```

This was working fine but I need to change the code because `resized_image.save(update_form.profile_image.path)` is giving error that backend doesn't support absolute path.

Comment: What is the value of `update_form.profile_image.path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To alter the cleaned_data use method `clean_<attibute>` like -

```
def clean_profile_image(self):
        if 'profile_image' in self.changed_data:
            p_image = self.cleaned_data.get('profile_image')
            print('self.cleaned_data',p_image)
            x,y,w,h = self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h
            image = Image.open(p_image)
            try:
                for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys() :
                    if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation]=='Orientation' : break
                exif=dict(image._getexif().items())
                if exif[orientation] == 3 :
                    image=image.rotate(180, expand=True)
                elif exif[orientation] == 6 :
                    image=image.rotate(270, expand=True)
                elif exif[orientation] == 8 :
                    image=image.rotate(90, expand=True)
            except:
                pass
            cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w+x, h+y))
            resized_image = cropped_image.resize((160, 160), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            filename = 'image'
            output = StringIO()
            resized_image.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=95)
            output.seek(0)
            new_image = InMemoryUploadedFile(output,'ImageField',\
        "%s.jpg" % filename , 'image/jpeg', resized_image.__sizeof__(), None)
            print('new_image',new_image)
            return new_image
```

also to initialize x,y,w,h in init -

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('data'):
            self.x = float(kwargs.get('data').get('x'))
            self.y = float(kwargs.get('data').get('y'))
            self.w = float(kwargs.get('data').get('width'))
            self.h = float(kwargs.get('data').get('height'))
            print(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h)
        return super(UpdateUserProfileForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```